# How does merging parallel branches in Git avoid introducing bugs?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I hope this doesn't sound too general; I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I'm learning how to use Git, and I just can't wrap my head around merging branches that are being worked on in parallel (I can understand linear workflows and the value of version control in linear scenarios, including having multiple branches for comparison, out of which only one will survive and the others will be discarded).

But I cannot see **how parallel branching can guarantee no conflicts** (the [Atlassian guide](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) calls it "a fail-safe mechanism for integrating code and sharing changes"). I would think that in a large project, it's quite possible for one change, which works on its own, to break another change, which also works on its own, but the guides I've read (and, later, the videos I've resorted to) seem to just be going around this point.

[This guy on Youtube](https://youtu.be/oPpnCh7InLY?t=505) claims that the only possible problem is when people are editing the same lines of code (in which case Git will require you to fix the conflict), but this is simply not true (I've managed to create a simple counter-example where edits at different places that worked while branched made the code buggy when merged, and Git reported no conflicts and a successful merge).

Sure, you could test the merged code and (maybe) catch the bug, but even so, that would mean somebody digging into the different branches' code to untangle it (thus defeating the claimed benefit of separate feature development).

I guess it *must* work somehow (otherwise, Linux and other large projects wouldn't have been possible), but I just haven't been able to find information as to **how**.

Comment: I think you're confusing fail-safe and fail-proof. The fail-safe nature of most workflows is a result of performing all code integration and testing on feature branches, then (and only then) merging the verified and tested code into master via a fast forward merge. This ensures that the inevitable bugs and breaks are never introduced into the mainline of your project..

Comment: Sure, I wasn't implying releasing software without testing; I was just saying that branching would make the piece-wise and modular aspect of development suffer from "non-linear" (in the mathematical sense) effects. But I guess Mark Adelsberger's answer addresses that to some extent.

Comment: I just realised I might be thinking about this "too mathematically" (as in "how can we prove it covers all possible cases?"). But at this point, we're talking more about project management than mathematics.

Comment: Exactly. "Mathematically", conflicts and bugs are guaranteed. A combination of good workflow, automated testing, and excellent software design is now we mitigate the risk associated with that certainty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making some bad assumptions.  Also, either you're getting information from bad sources, or those bad assumptions are leading you to misinterpret the information you're getting.

Merging is not guaranteed to be bug free, and nobody who knows what they're talking about would say that it is.  *However,* it is rare in practice for two patches in a large *but well-designed* system to break one another unless there is a direct code conflict.

You should absolutely be testing every version, including merge results.  This is one of the reasons I dislike casual history rewrites (e.g. workflows that depend on obsessive rebasing to keep the history perfectly linear): because nobody in practice tests all the auto-generated versions that result from those workflows.  It's also why you need solid unit tests covering the defined behavior of your system.  (People mistakenly think tests need to "cover the code"; that is nonsense.  They need to cover the requirements.)  Good unit tests are fast and automated, so you run them with every build anyway.

And yes, in the rare instance where a merge introduces a bug, you have to hunt it down.  Just like when a bug is introduced by hand and not immediately noticed, you have to hunt it down.

There is support in git for doing the hunting (such as the `bisect` command), which is useful as long as you generally make sure every commit you retain is a "clean" version (builds and passes the defined test suite).  But even at that, if you know that both of the merge's immediate parents work on their own, then you should usually be able to examine the diff between the merge commit and one of its parents and find the bug there, without even needing to dig into the history.

Comment: Good point. Git doesn’t protect from bugs, but it sure helps to find them.

Comment: OK, this makes sense, and I think the critical point is a "well-designed system"; i.e., there are additional requirements/restrictions for this process to work well.

Comment: I guess my "bad assumptions" might be taking "fail-safe" to mean "fail-proof" (as LightBender commented) or taking the Youtube guy's "no problem" to mean "no bug", whereas he might have meant "no error message from Git".